# FCP: Shape disappears when made into a compound clip

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I'm having a problem in Final Cut Pro X (10.3.4) where when I create a *New Compound Clip* with a shape, the shape disappears.

- Screenshot 1 below shows the shape before making the compound clip
- Screenshot 2 shows me selecting the two clips and right clicking to make *New Compound Clip*
- Screenshot 3 shows the resulting compound clip - note how the shape is no longer visible

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]